# Using grep command for multiple strings

Tags: linux, bash, text-processing, grep

How do I write logic for

```
Test total=100
Test scored=80 
Tests failed=0
```

I need to write in a bash file the script to check if `Test total`, `Test scored` and `Tests failed=0` exists in a file. I need to use grep command.. but how do i check for new line in this case?

Also the number 100,80, I don't need to look for. Just the text before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    grep -e "Test total=[0-9][0-9]*$" -e "Test scored=[0-9][0-9]*$" -e "Tests failed=[0-9][0-9]*$" foofile
```

Considering you only intend to match the first 3 lines for the input given below:

```
 Test total=100
 Test scored=80
 Tests failed=0

 Test total=100 alpha
 Test scored=80 beta
 Tests failed=0 gamma

 Test total=
 Test scored=
 Tests failed=
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @StephenRauch, thanks for pointing my mistake. I misread the question. Now I amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using bash and grep, you can test the return status of multiple grep call in a function like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
failed_zero () {
    grep -q "Test total" "$1" || grep -q "Test scored" "$1" || grep -q "Test failed=0" "$1"
    return $?
}

# test first file name on command line
failed_zero $1
echo $?
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
found=$( egrep  "Test total|Test scored|Tests failed" -c  file )
if [ $found -eq 3 ]
then
  ## all three test
else
  ## some failed
fi
```

where

- `egrep` allow extended grep, that is the use of `|` (or)
- `-c` give count of matched lines.
- `$( )` return the result of command as a variable.